# Using KeyStore and Cipher for a user controlled program

Tags: java, encryption, keystore

I'm currently a novice on crypto and using it in Java so I decided to make a program that encrypts/ decrypts data using an asymmetrical method (Secret keys) and AES. Right now I only have the class that creates and stores the key in a keystore instance. this is my code:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class KeyGen
{

public KeyGen()
{
}

public void createKey()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing...");
        KeyGenerator keyG = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); //Creates instance of KeyGenerator using algorithm "AES"
        int keyBitSize = 128; //Key bit size
        keyG.init(keyBitSize); //Initializes keyG

        System.out.println("Generating...");

        SecretKey secKey = keyG.generateKey();
        System.out.println("Finishing...");

        //Creates keystore, gets and creates password array
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        System.out.println("Enter Password For Key: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass = in.next();
        char[] keyPassword = pass.toCharArray();

        //Initializes keystore
        int choice = 0;
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!(choice == 1) && !(choice == 2))
        {
            System.out.println("Create a new KeyStore or access another? (1/2)");
            try
            {
                choice = in2.nextInt();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

        }
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
            try
            {
                fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fis != null)
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
            keystore.load(fis, keyPassword);
            System.out.println("Keystore created. Stored: False");
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter keyStore name to load: ");
            String keyStoreName = in.next();
            java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
            try
            {
                fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(keyStoreName);
                keystore.load(fis, keyPassword);

            }
            finally
            {
                if (fis != null)
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Keystore loaded. Stored: False");
        }

        //Adds the Key to the Keystore
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secKey);
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter entryPassword = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPassword); //Sets pass to protParam for the keystore
        System.out.println("Please enter your key alias: ");
        String alias = in.nextLine();
        keystore.setEntry(alias, secretKeyEntry, entryPassword); //adds key as entry to the keystore
        System.out.println("Enter keyStore name to save as: ");
        String newKeyStoreName = in.nextLine();
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(newKeyStoreName);
            keystore.store(fos, keyPassword);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fos != null)
            {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("KeyStore successfully stored. Key Alias: " + alias);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

I'm not sure that i'm being completely efficient in my use of Keystore, but here is my main question: How would I use this to decrypt/encrypt data in an external class? I don't know how to work with cipher either so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me try and figure this out. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) i can understand the `getInstance` but everything beyond that is a mystery to me in terms of how to use it in this context.